# What exactly is required to allow building a tower on a mound?

Tags: kingdom-new-lands

It's necessary to clear the trees around a mound to build a tower there, but there also appears to be a short delay before one can build.

How large a distance must be cleared, when can one build? What exactly are the requirements?

Comment: The delay is when anything is cleared, it takes time for the background and land to update to the new terrain. If you chop down a single tree, this is typically only a few seconds. So if you had a mound, and a single tree nearby, chopping down the tree would mean you are able to build a wall in 5-10s, but unfortunately I have no definitive information besides "I've played the game for 50h"